# Trying to pass Doubles from a view to an another but it doesn't work

Tags: swift, swift3, double

Hey I'm a newbie to Swift and Xcode and I am trying to make a little app but I have an error and can't fix it.

I'm trying to passe a double from a view to another but it says 
Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and "int"

That's my first view :

```
@IBOutlet weak var Rned: UILabel!
var ArgentC: Double = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Rned.text = String(ArgentC)
    Rned.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Rectangle2")!)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SacocheVCp2
    SecondViewController.ArgentCV = Rned.text!
}

@IBAction func Reset(_ sender: Any) {
    Rned.text = String(0)
    ArgentC = 0
}
@IBAction func CashButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueSac", sender: self)

}
```

and that is my second view with the error, and the error appears when I want to add numbers to my doubles.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Rend2Label: UILabel!

var ArgentCV = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Rend2Label.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Label")!)

    Rend2Label.text = ArgentCV


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func CinqEur(_ sender: Any) {
    ArgentCV += 5     // <== Here
    Rend2Label.text = ArgentCV
}
@IBAction func DixEur(_ sender: Any) {
    ArgentCV += 10    // <== Here
}
@IBAction func VingtEur(_ sender: Any) {
    ArgentCV += 20    // <== Here
}
@IBAction func CinquanteEur(_ sender: Any) {
    ArgentCV += 50    // <== Here
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: start var / method names with small letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to send it as a `String` , you can send it as `Int`

```
secondViewController.argentCV = Int(rned.text) ?? 0 // ?? to avoid crashes  but make sure it doesn't destroy logic
```

Then inside `SacocheVCp2`

```
var argentCV = 0 // 0 is default
```

Finally

```
argentCV += 5     // <== Here
rend2Label.text = "\(argentCV)"
```

Comment: Thank you I’ll try this tonight